# Win10 Professional Dockerizing Augular App gives: unknown instruction: EXPAND-ARCHIVE

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, docker

I am going to create a docker image of angular web application to other windows machine. When it comes to the command execution :

```
docker build -t node .
```

It gives the following exception:

```
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 10: unknown instruction: EXPAND-ARCHIVE
```

Would you please tell me how to correct the line 10 so that the zip file can be extracted ?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803 as installer

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.11.0
ENV NODE_SHA256 7b2409605c871a40d60c187bd24f6f6ddf10590df060b7d905ef46b3b3aa7f81

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.0/node-v8.11.0-win-x64.zip";
Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; 
Rename-Item "C:\\node-v8.11.0-win-x64" c:\nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1803

WORKDIR C:\nodejs
COPY --from=installer C:\nodejs\ .
RUN SETX PATH C:\nodejs
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

WORKDIR /app

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY src/WebSpa/package.json /app/src/WebSpa/package.json

WORKDIR /app/src/WebSpa
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

# add app
COPY . /app

# start app
CMD cd /app/src/WebSpa && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a line return in your Dockerfile RUN command, causing it not to chain the powershell commands but instead try and execute the second one as a Docker command.

It should look like this:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.0/node-v8.11.0-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; Rename-Item "C:\\node-v8.11.0-win-x64" c:\nodejs
```

Comment: it runs smoothly and goes Step 1,2,3 . and so on. Thanks